# Mysql select next and previous ID in match boolean mode

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to find next and previous ID in Match boolean mode. This is what i tried:

```
SELECT id
FROM songs 
WHERE MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

Result:

```
32212
32138
32221
32235
```

SQL Fiddle(Result): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d369d/7

Then find the next ID after id 32138:

```
SELECT id
FROM songs 
WHERE 
    id < '32138'
  AND 
    MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC LIMIT 1
```

According to above result, the next id should be 32221 but the result is empty.

SQL Fiddle(Next ID): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d369d/9

Any help please?

Comment: `32221` is greater than `32138` so how do you want to find it? I think your problem is `id < '32138'` should be changed to `id > '32138'`

Comment: @SaUce I've tried `id > '32138'` but the result return `'32212'`.

Comment: it is what @Gordon said. you were comparing IDs not comparing ORDER of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing *id*s in the `where` clause, and you are looking for an `id` value less than the lowest `id`.  You want to compare to the `match` result:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM songs s cross join
     (select MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as matchresult
      from songs s
      where id = 32138
     ) s32138
WHERE MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) < s32138.matchresult and
      MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

EDIT:

Of course, multiple songs can have the same match value.  To take this into account:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM songs s cross join
     (select id, MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as matchresult
      from songs s
      where id = 32138
     ) scomp
WHERE (MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) < scomp.matchresult or
       MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) = scomp.matchresult and s.id < scomp.id

      ) and
      MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH (artist) AGAINST ('alpha delta beta' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Weird, I can get the `id '32221'` with above code but I tried another id(32221) in the query the result return 0. It should return `id '32235'`. Any idea? SQl Fiddle: [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d369d/24

Comment: @richard . . . The two lowest scoring ids are 32221 and 32235.  The query produces a stable sort, first by score then by id descending.  There is no id lower than 32221.  If you want by id ascending, change `s.id < scomp.id` to `scomp.id < s.id`.

Comment: By the way, if i want to get previous ID, what should i change in the code?

Comment: @richard . . . You want to change the order of the conditions in the `where` clause and the `desc` to `asc` in the `order by`, I think.